# Как узнать размер базы данных PostgreSQL?

Tags: база-данных, postgresql

Есть база PostgreSQL `base`, пользователь `postgres`. Как одной командой, не используя скриптов, получить размер базы?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Войти в интерактивный терминал:

```
$ sudo -u postgres psql
```

Выполнить запрос:

```
# select pg_database_size('base');
```

Comment: SELECT pg_size_pretty( pg_database_size( 'sample_db' ) );

Comment: @Vetal4eg Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш вариант решения отдельным ответом. Уверен, он может помочь многим вашим коллегам!

Answer (score 21):

В человеческом виде размер базы покажет обёртка pg_size_pretty

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty( pg_database_size( 'sample_db' ) );

 pg_size_pretty 
----------------
36 GB
```

Таким же макаром можно посмотреть и размер таблицы (с индексами)

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty( pg_total_relation_size( 'table' ) );

 pg_size_pretty 
----------------
 6341 MB
```

Если нужно без индексов, тогда запрос другой:

```
# SELECT pg_size_pretty( pg_relation_size( 'table' ) );

 pg_size_pretty 
----------------
 1341 MB
```

Answer (score 1):

Размер всех БД построчно:

```sql
select datname, pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size(datname))
from pg_database
```

Общий размер всех БД одним значением:

```sql
select pg_size_pretty(sum(pg_database_size(datname)))
from pg_database
```

Answer (score 0):

`\l+` человекоформатированные данные в 7 колонке будут